# How to code this linear program in IBM CPLEX?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

How can I code the linear program using IBM CPLEX?

[image: In this picture u,v represent the edge of the graph.]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In the future, please do not just link to images. Instead, please spend the time to describe the problem textually, so that others can help you more easily. See [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the ternary operator.

Let me give you a starting point:

```
{int} E=asSet(1..10);

int V[u in E,v in E]=u+v;

int nbK=2;
int nbN=4;

range N=1..nbN;
range K=1..nbK;

int U[k in K]=2*k;
int C0=1;

dvar boolean y[E][E];
dvar boolean x[E][E][K];

minimize sum(u,v in E) y[u][v]*V[u][v];

subject to
{

forall(u,v in E,k in K) 
{
forall(k in K) sum(w in N) x[u][w][k]-sum(v in N) x[v][u][k]==  
( (u==C0)?1:(u==U[k]?-1:0) );

forall(u,v in E,k in K) x[u][v][k]<=y[u][v];
}
}
```